# Office Add-in not available in Powerpoint online store

Tags: office-store

@Office-Store, 
We have an issue with our O365 add-in. It isn't showing on the Powerpoint online store (It is showing on all other supported products).
After investigations we are assuming the issue is with the store hence we are reaching out for assistance.

We have ran the manifest validation tool and it is showing that we are supported with powerpoint online. See products supported in following link: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381889?src=Manufacturing&tab=Overview. 
When we site load the add-ins manifest it is also working as expected for Powerpoint online. We have seen this online add-in working previously.

These are the requirements in our manifest:

```
<Hosts>
   <Host Name="Presentation" />
   <Host Name="Document" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
     <Set Name="DialogApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
     <Set Name="ImageCoercion" MinVersion="1.1"/>
   </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Since the Vidigami Add-in is available for desktop applications (Powerpoint and Word) as well as Word online we expect the Add-in to be available in the Powerpoint Online store.

Comment: If I search for your Vidigami add-in in PowerPoint online store, I can see it.

Comment: I was able to get assistance from Microsoft Dev Support